# Issues with facebook profile model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-facebook

I am using facebook_connect with my app.

I want to import user profile model to my app.....But it gives me an error of

**from facebook_connect.models import FacebookProfileModel**

**ImportError: cannot import name FacebookProfileModel**

my model.py is as:-

```
from facebook_connect.models import FacebookProfileModel
class MyCustomProfile(FacebookProfileModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
```

I am using this functionality first time and I am using this [doc](http://django-facebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for reference. so any body can help me where I am wrong or I have to add something in my model.

*Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your import statement is incorrect, and should be `django_facebook` not `facebook_connect`.

From the docs:

```
from django_facebook.models import FacebookProfileModel

class MyCustomProfile(FacebookProfileModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
    ....
```

Comment: I have installed this **facebook_connect** in my  so I have to use this when I am importing and if I use as you suggested then it too gives the error of module not found.And as i said I am follow the doc(link is given in my question ) you can see that hoe I install this and why I am using facebook_connect.

Comment: and I have installed this **pip install django-facebook-connect** not this  **pip install django_facebook.**